# Multiple Conditions in Javascript If Statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

this is an embarrassingly basic question but I haven't been able to find anything I understood to be an answer on MDN, W3schools, here, or Google searching.

When referring to multiple conditions, like within an if statement:

```
if ((a != b) && (a != c) && (a != d)){...}
```

(considering how nastily long the list can get,) there must be a more efficient way to do it. I imagine it would look similar to this:

```
if (a != (b || c || d)){...}
```

That doesn't work, but there must be some other efficient solution. Let me know if you can. Thanks.

EDIT: apparently valuable info: all variables are primitives.

Comment: It depends on what `a` and `b` and `c` are,..

Comment: Possibly `if (![b, c, d].includes(a))` if all are primitives.

Comment: @JMcFar  Yes, like CRise has shown, if they are simple primitives you can place them in an array and use includes..   So for numbers CRise solution will work fine.  For none primitives it may even work too, depending on how you use this technique.

Comment: @Keith Really? In the specific case I'm working on they're strings.

Comment: @JMcFar `strings` are primitives.   So will work fine too.

Comment: @CRice that worked! I don't understand how yet, but it does. I'll do some research to try to understand but if I still don't I might ask you a question on here if you don't mind. If you want to submit an answer I can mark yours as the solution

Comment: @CRice just want to make sure youre not bothering formatting into an official answer. I gave another guy the 'acceptance'

Comment: @JMcFar If an answer solves your problem you should accept it regardless of who authored it. Danziger's answer has my upvote. We're just glad we could help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an `Array` with all the possible values and use [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) or [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check whether a give value is or is not inside that `Array`:

```js
const values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9];

console.log(`[${ values.join(', ') }].indexOf(1) = ${ values.indexOf(1) }`);
console.log(`[${ values.join(', ') }].indexOf(6) = ${ values.indexOf(6) }`);
console.log(`[${ values.join(', ') }].includes(1) = ${ values.includes(1) }`);
console.log(`[${ values.join(', ') }].includes(6) = ${ values.includes(6) }`);
```

As you can see, `indexOf()` will return `-1` if the value is not inside the `Array` or the index of its first occurrence otherwise, which might be useful depending on your use case, while `includes()` only returns `true` if the value is present or `false` otherwise, and it's not supported in IE.

So in your case, you would end up with something like this:

```js
const b = 'b';
const c = 'c';
const d = 'd';

const values = [b, c, d];

let target = 'a';

if (!values.includes(target)){
  console.log(`${ target } not in [${ values.join(', ') }]`);
}

target = 'b';

if (values.includes('b')){
  console.log(`${ target } in [${ values.join(', ') }]`);
}

// You could also do [b, c, d].includes(target) if you don't need to reuse that Array.
```

This will work with [primitive values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive), so [string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/string), [number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/number), [boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/boolean), [null](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/null), [undefined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/undefined) and [symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/symbol), **but also with [`Object` references](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Object_reference), not to be confused with just [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)**, as you can see below:

```js
const values = [{ foo: 1 }, { bar: 2 }, { baz: 3 }];
const target = { foo: 1 };

console.log(`values.includes(target) = ${ values.includes(target) }`);

// This will not work because the { foo: 1 } object inside values and the one we are passing to
// includes are not the same, as you can see here:

console.log(`values[0] === target = ${ values[0] === target }`);

// However, if we get a reference to it, then those two references can be compared successfully:

const reference = values[0];

console.log(`values[0] === reference = ${ values[0] === reference }`);

// So now we can also use includes or indexOf:

console.log(`values.includes(reference) = ${ values.includes(reference) }`);
```

If you want to understand how this works, you could try to implement a function similar to `indexOf` or `includes` yourself. Something simple like:

```js
function isValueInArray(arr, value) {

  const size = arr.length;
  
  // Iterate over all the indexes in arr:
  for (let i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
  
    // Check whether the value at the current index matches the target value:
    if (arr[i] === value) {
    
      // If so, we have found value at index i in arr, so we return true and stop searching:
      return true;
      
      // Note we could also return the index if we care about the position the value is at.
    }
  }
  
  // We have checked all the values in arr and none of them matched, so we return false: 
  return false;
}

const values = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9];

console.log(`isValueInArray(values, 1) = ${ isValueInArray(values, 1) }`);
console.log(`isValueInArray(values, 6) = ${ isValueInArray(values, 6) }`);
```

However, keep in mind a real implementation is slightly more complicated. For example, you could take a look at [this polyfill for `includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#Polyfill).

Comment: Thanks! This is correct. However I'm in an awkward position of not knowing precise stackoverflow etiquette-- @CRice answered in a comment on my post earlier and solved it for me first, so I'm not sure if I should mark yours as the solution or wait for him to format his to an answer... hrrrmmm :/
EDIT: screw it, you technically did the 'answering' first and it clearly took more of your time, WINNER. thanks again

Comment: @JMcFar Thanks (: At the end, the decision is up to you, but you can find some guidelines here https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work. Some users prefer to send a quick and short answer first and then edit it to add more details, while others spend a bit more time writing a detailed one at first. You can also read about that here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem